# Cannot read property 'match' of undefined at Ember.DefaultResolver.extend.podBasedComponentsInSubdir

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm getting a really opaque error message (opaque in the sense I have no point of reference for my own source) from console, I'm not entirely sure where to look, I feel it's likely an error in library code but before posting this on github I'll just double check it's not my own fault.

## The Problem

The Problem is simple, I'm calling `this.store.find('player')`, in hopes to get a list of all players, and then display them in some kind of list, but I'm not even getting past the loading part. The data is pulled from the server and looks properly formatted, but something seems to be failing after the `route.model` method call. And the error message seems to be somewhere in the `ember.js` library code with nothing pointing back to my own code.

## Server Response

The content type is of course `application/json`, and note the `id` property is actually `_id`.

```
[
  {
    "_id":"55405a5102b4ed623c225e87",
    "alias":"mikeTest",
    "__v":0,
    "scans":[],
    "createdAt":"2015-04-29T04:13:05.223Z"
  }
]
```

## Error message

Note there is part of the stack trace pointing to my source, only `Ember` source. Which has made this a pain to debug.

```
Error while processing route: leader Cannot read property 'match' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at Ember.DefaultResolver.extend.podBasedComponentsInSubdir (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:60138:76)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:60190:34
    at Array.exports.default.mixin.Mixin.create.find (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:39572:30)
    at Ember.DefaultResolver.extend.findModuleName (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:60188:44)
    at resolveOther (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:60051:37)
    at superWrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:28141:20)
    at exports.default.EmberObject.default.extend.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:15454:35)
    at Object.resolve [as resolver] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:15217:23)
    at resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12792:29)
    at Object.Registry.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12336:21)
```

## Source

This ember app is very young, so there is very little source at the moment, but this is all the relevant source at the moment.

### Routes

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('leader');
  this.resource('profile');
  this.route('loading');
});
```

### Leader route

Leader has a template and a controller, but they are basically empty right now.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      players: this.get('store').find('player')
    });
  },
});
```

### Player Model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  alias: DS.attr('string'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  scans: DS.hasMany('scan'),
});
```

### Application Adapter

```
import DS from 'ember-data';


export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: ''
});
```

### Application Serialiser

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: function (type) {
    return '_id';
  },

  serializeId: function(id) {
    return id.toString();
  }
});
```

## Versions

I'm not sure if any of the versions here are particularly important

- `ember-cli` is **0.2.3**
- `ember-data` is **1.0.0-beta.16.1**
- `ember` is **1.11.1**

## Things I've tried

- removing properties from the model, in the event the relationships seemed to be the problem (nothing changed)
- tried setting up a serialiser and adapter for the application (included above), nothing changed.

  - the serialiser in the event that the `id` field in the response is actually `_id`.
- tried updating ember data, nothing changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay I figured out what was being done wrong... I forgot to check if the data being returned by the server abides to the convention/protocol required to use ember data. The `JSON` returned by the server looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "_id":"55405a5102b4ed623c225e87",
    "alias":"mikeTest",
    "__v":0,
    "scans":[],
    "createdAt":"2015-04-29T04:13:05.223Z"
  }
]
```

It should actually look like this

```
{
  "players": [
    {
      "_id":"55405a5102b4ed623c225e87",
      "alias":"mikeTest",
      "__v":0,
      "scans":[],
      "createdAt":"2015-04-29T04:13:05.223Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

So yes this was me being dumb and missing something.

### Why is this Required

Ember data expects JSON returned from the server to meet the [JSON API Standard](http://jsonapi.org), which is a standard that specifies the formatting of the JSON returned from a server. In this case, the data didn't meet the **JSON API** standard, as I forgot to put the array of players under a key called `players`. There are some more examples of this in the [Ember v1.10.0 guide to models](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/the-rest-adapter/).

The reason Ember Data expects this is so Ember Data can make the certain assumptions about the data returned from the server.

Comment: where (in which file) did you put this code that you linked to? ```extractDeleteRecord: function(store, type, payload) {
  // payload is {delete: true} and then ember data wants to go ahead and set
  // the new properties, return null so it doesn't try to do that
  return null;
}```

Comment: per SO etiquette,instead of just saying what's wrong, you should provide an answer (not just a link) that shows exactly how to fix the problem.

Comment: I don't fully understand your first comment though, are you talking about the code that returns the JSON from the server?

Comment: If you changed your client side Ember code to deal with the fact that the server is returning json in a different format than expected, can you show how you altered Ember code to adapt to that (or did you rewrite The server side code to respond with json data in the expected format)?

Comment: Oh right, I rewrote the server side code. I don't think there's a non hacky way to rewrite the client side code for ember-data anymore unless you write your own adapter or something along those lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79003/discussion-between-abot-and-leahcim).